# multiple dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

How can I build a nested dictionary from reading configure files in Python, such that I can access it like this:

```
multi_dict["name1"]["name2"]["name3"] = some_value
```

My current approach is:

```
if name1 not in dict:
    dict["name1"] = {}
    dict["name1"]["name2"] = {}
```

(etc.)

But this ways seems so boring!  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

The configure files that I'm reading are like the following:

```
[a1]
key1=value1
[a2]
[.a3]
key2=value2
[..a4]
key3=value3
```

The `.` prefixes mean "another level of nesting". So in this example, I would set:

```
dict[a1][key1]=value1
dict[a2][a3][key2]=value2
dict[a2][a3][a4][key3]=value3
```

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify what I think you were asking (and to improve the formatting).  It's actually a pretty good question; however, it got immediately closed because it was formatted pretty poorly.  If I didn't understand what you were asking, feel free to edit.

Comment: Well, you can make inner dictionary first and add them to upper dictionary… No? But it depend a lot of type of data you have!

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: I think the question is: "how I can do that in a shorter way". No?

Comment: @Clodion shorter and elegant are often synonyms ;). If this gets reopened, I think using `multi_dict = {}; multi_dict.setdefault({})` or similar would work.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: Yes, but not always! ;-) `multi_dic` seems very efficient… But wait and see for the data structure!!